# Include directory off-by one in libxml2 for nix

Tags: gcc, libxml2, include-path, nix

I'm bundling a `.cpp` program that depends on `libxml`, but `g++` cannot find it. I've done the appropriate steps to make `libxml` available, however the directory structure is slightly different than the source expects. I want to know about nix-based solutions to this problem.

The compiler (from a nix-shell session) says that `libxml` is not in my system path:

```
fatal error: libxml/encoding.h: No such file or directory
#include <libxml/encoding.h>
```

However, it should be. In my .nix file I made sure to included `libxml2`

```
buildInputs = [ ... libxml2 ...];
```

and my `nix-shell` environment confirms that the library is present:

```
NIX_CFLAGS_COMPILE= [...] -isystem /nix/store/zf1nyqyx2zd6y944ln2rxnhd5m4265n4-libxml2-2.9.9-dev/include  [...]
```

If I look in that directory, I find the search path is off. The path to the file is actually (relative to NIX_CFLAGS_COMPILE path):

```
libxml2/libxml/encoding.h
```

I found that I can compensate for this off-by-one path error by adding the following option to my compile command:

```
-isystem /nix/store/zf1nyqyx2zd6y944ln2rxnhd5m4265n4-libxml2-2.9.9-dev/include/libxml2
```

(The same path as the `NIX_CFLAGS_COMPILE`, but starting at the `libxml2` directory.)

Given that information, I am wondering about a nix-based solution to this problem. The source is not mine, so changing them is the last thing I want to do. I see two other options.

First, I could add the path in the makefile that is triggered during `buildPhase`. However, I'm not exactly sure how to simply grab that path. For instance, inheriting `libxml2` in my derivation makes the `libxm2-2.9.9-bin` directory available, when I need the `libxml2-2.9.9-dev`. I suppose I could `grep` or `sed` on the `NIX_CFLAGS_COMPILE` path, but I'd rather not.

My preferred solution would be to make a simple `libxml` derivation based off the `libxml2` and just add that to my buildInputs, but that seems like it might not be simple either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `pkg-config --cflags libxml-2.0` to get the appropriate compiler options.

If everything is configured correctly, it will find the appropriate `/nix/store/*-libxml2-2.9.9-dev/lib/pkgconfig/libxml-2.0.pc` file on your computer, and extract the needed compiler options from that.

You could invoke GCC using a one-liner like this:

```
g++ program.cpp $(pkg-config --libs --cflags libxml-2.0) -o program
```

This is a general solution that doesn't just apply to Nix, but you should be able to get it to work in Nix by ensuring you have the `pkg-config` utility on your PATH and ensuring the proper environment variables are set so that it can find libxml2.  Nix probably has a bunch of shell scripts or something to help you set up your environment in that way, because this is a common need.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by defining a `libxml` attribute in my derivation and adding that to my `buildInputs`. The new library is just a link to the old, but with path corrected for. Here's the relevant parts of the derivation:

```
{ stdenv, libxml2, ... } : stdenv.mkDerivation
rec
{ buildInputs = [ libxml ];
  libxml = stdenv.mkDerivation {
    name = "libxml" ;
    system = builtins.currentSystem;
    outputs = [ "bin" "dev" "out" ];
    phases = ["buildPhase"];
    buildPhase =
      ''echo "my command out = $out"
        echo ${libxml2.dev}
        mkdir -p $out
        mkdir -p $dev
        mkdir -p $bin
        ln -s ${libxml2.dev}/include/libxml2 $dev/include
        ln -s ${libxml2.dev}/lib $dev/lib
      ''; };
}
```